# HttpMethod, Responses, Code WebApi .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp, asp.net-core

Estoy buscando en base a clases nativas de `.net` obtener los siguientes valores

`HttpMethod` ( **Ya lo conseguí** ), 
`Responses` ( **Aún no lo obtengo** ) ,
`Code` ( **Aún no lo tengo, pero se refleja en Network del navegador** )

Cabe destacar, que  el Responses, puede ser:

> - application/json
> - text/plain
> - text/json

[image: Mi código, donde se visualiza el code ( por el navegador) y el Method]

Comment: Creo que la pregunta no es clara, pudieras extender lo que estas buscando?

Comment: Listo, ya genere una nueva estructura en la pregunta. Saludos